# Magento 2 email template edit url in html page

Tags: php, magento, onclick, magento2

I'm trying to redirect to external URL with token in email template html path:

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password_reset_confirmation.html

I copy the html to my file in my path

> /app/design/frontend/My_THEME/Magento_Customer/email/password_reset_confirmation.html

the code

```
<a href="{{var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword/',[_query:[token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}" target="_blank">{{trans "Set a New Password"}}</a>        </td>
```

I need to redirect this url to extrnal url, I tried:

````
<a href="{{var this.getUrl('https://www.my-simple.com/reset-password/',[_query:[token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}" target="_blank">{{trans "Set a New Password"}}</a>```

but not working,
any help please
````

Comment: Did you try to add $store before your custom url in updated code?